# AWS SQS message concurrent processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have connected an SQS to a lambda(Lambda 1). The lambda(Lambda 1) makes API calls to a service.
I have to seed 1000 messages at once. For that, I am sending 1000 messages to SQS with the help of another lambda(Lambda 2). The problem I am facing is that the SQS triggers 1000 lambda which makes 1000 API calls to my service leading to service unavailability.

Can I configure the SQS frequency for example, in 1 second the SQS should only process 10 or 100 messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Limiting a lambda function's allowed concurrency

In short you set how many concurrent executions this lambda can have

[image]

Intro: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/set-concurrency-limits-on-individual-aws-lambda-functions/

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html

Comment: Won't it result in throttling? After changing concurrency to 1 the lambda started throttling.